# ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front keeps popping up?

Tags: android

I am new to the Android Development Tools world and i just downloaded the Eclipse and ADT plugin on my laptop. I just made a button by following a video tutorial I watched online and it wouldn’t work on the emulator, so I tried connecting my android phone to the laptop and downloaded the drivers needed. On the android device the package itself would pop up, but the button I made would not. The message

> ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has
>   been brought to the front

would always pop up on the console after saying all of the following:

```
Android Launch! 
[2014-07-24 08:22:11 - PLEASEBUTTON] adb is running normally. 
[2014-07-24 08:22:11 - PLEASEBUTTON] Performing com.example.pleasebutton.MainActivity activity launch 
[2014-07-24 08:22:13 - PLEASEBUTTON] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall. 
[2014-07-24 08:22:13 - PLEASEBUTTON] Starting activity com.example.pleasebutton.MainActivity on device 3934C3A970FE00EC 
[2014-07-24 08:22:13 - PLEASEBUTTON] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.pleasebutton/.MainActivity } 
[2014-07-24 08:22:14 - PLEASEBUTTON] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

I still have no idea what is going on, and I really want to solve this.

```
package com.example.pleasebutton;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Build;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


 }
 public void onClick(View v){}   
 public void buttonBtn (View v) {
     Toast.makeText(this,"You just pressed a button",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }
}
```

here is the activity xml file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.pleasebutton.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

and here is the fragment xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.pleasebutton.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/awesomebutton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="buttonBtn"
    android:text="Cool Button" />
```

Comment: close the application before building it to the device

Comment: I have been doing that, you mean just going back to the home screen on the phone and then running the program again right?

Comment: im not making a app for the camera, its a button and the button wont appear on the screen. after I run the program the phone will just open to the android application but the screen is blank and the button is not there

Comment: Can you provide the activity_main.xml file?

Comment: oh my sorry i was commenting on the wrong thread, deleting comment now.. sorry

Comment: there is a fragment xml file and a sctivity _main.xml file,

Comment: that was the activity main xml file

Comment: sorry i just posted both the activity xml file and the fragment xml file

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button bAfficher;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Assign graphical button to attribute

        bAfficher = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.awesomebutton);



        bAfficher.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 Toast.makeText(this,"You just pressed a button",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }
});
}
}
```